# MYSQL Select if condition matches ANYTHING in Column1 and Column2

Tags: mysql

How do I get the city if my codition has a match in Categroy and Catecode

```
"id"    "City"      "category"  "CatCode" "country"
"1"     "NewYork"   "0"         "101"     "US"
"2"     "Alaska"    "1"         "102"     "US"
"3"     "NewOrln"   "3"         "101"     "US"
"4"     "MashSh"    "4"         "102"     "US"
```

Please, can you help with a query for this?
Thank you.

I need the results
Example
If Say Select Country if Category = 4 And CateCode = 101
I need result to be US 
Since 4 exists in Category and 101 exists in CateCode.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want something like this:

```
SELECT country
FROM theTable
WHERE country IN (SELECT country FROM theTable WHERE category = 4)
   AND country IN (SELECT country FROM theTable WHERE catcode = 101)
```

that represents what I think you are looking for a little more directly/literally; but technically, this should be faster (since it has one less subquery):

```
SELECT country
FROM theTable
WHERE category = 4
   AND country IN (SELECT country FROM theTable WHERE catcode = 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search the cities that match, e.g., in category=3 and catcode=101 in your table:

```
Select city from your_table_name WHERE category=3 AND catcode=101;
```

Comment: It doesnt work if condition exists on different indexes
And thats what I want to get

For example 

Select city from your_table_name WHERE category=3 AND catcode=102;

Even though Category 3 and CateCode 102 are on diffrent index

Comment: The result, based in your 4 elements, for "Select city from your_table_name WHERE category=3 AND catcode=102;" will be 'Empty set'. Do not?

Comment: Use OR, the filtering condition should be a disjunction.

Comment: I would concur with @cdaiga. Except if you want the country returned only if category[4] = US and CatCode[101] = US. In this case, you will need to evaluate two different selects.

Answer (score 0):

You need a disjoint condition.

```
 select city from your_table_name where  
 catcode=101 OR category=3;
```